# What if $(a) \land (b) \iff (c)$ and $(c)$ is false?

Tags: real-analysis, logic

My question is about the logical inverse of this Lemma:

> **Lemma**: Let $g$ be a real analytic function. Then we have the equivalence $((a)∧(b))⇔(c)$, where the statements $(a),(b)$ and $(c)$ are given by:
>
> (a) $g$ has infinitely many real zeros and the set of those zeros is unbounded in both directions.
>
> (b) $g$ assumes arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small values, i.e., for all $K>0$, there are $s_1,s_2$ with $g(s_1)<-K$ and $g(s_2)>K$,
>
> (c) The fiber $g^{-1}(w)$ is infinite for all $w\in \Bbb R$.

In particular, what if for some $w \in \Bbb R$, the fiber $g^{-1}(w)$ is finite?

Comment: What is your question? This is a lemma, not an implication. It doesn't even *have* a converse to ask a question about...

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I mean the logical inverse.

Comment: The lemma is a logical truth. Its negation will be a contradiction. It's really not clear what you're asking. Please consider adding more context, e.g. what you want to use it for, and where you encountered it.

Comment: I want to see the equivalence for this case: The fiber $g^{-1}(w)$ is finite for some $w\in \Bbb R$

Comment: @Lord_Farin: You may be interested to know that the Lemma is actually *false*. See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/557175/28900) if you're curious. (Let me know if you see any errors.)

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks for the pointer, and +1 on your answer! I found no errors while scrutinizing your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lemma establishes that $(c)$ and the conjunction of $(a)$ and $(b)$ are *logically equivalent*.

In particular, if $(c)$ is false, so must $(a) \land (b)$ be. Concretely, this means $(a)$ or $(b)$ must be false.

That is, we infer that at least one of the following must be the case:

- (The negation of $(a)$, that is:) The set of zeroes of $g$ is bounded in at least one direction;
- (The negation of $(b)$, that is:) $g$ is either bounded above or bounded below.

I suggest you think for a moment on why these are indeed the negations of $(a)$ and $(b)$, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can negate both sides of if and only if, that is there is no difference between $(a \land b )\iff c$ and $\neg(a \land b) \iff \neg c$. Then If $\neg c$, then $\neg (a \land b)$, then $\neg a \vee \neg b$ according to De Morgan's rule.

Comment: $\iff$ is rendered by `\iff`. I've edited to incorporate this.